# Call to deleted function 'addressof' in ctor/dtor

Tags: c++

I don't know there is `std::addressof` available in c++ standard library until today I read some blog. In my understanding, if `opeartor &` is overloaded, then `std::addressof` should be used, otherwise it's not necessary to use `std::addressof`, it should be equivalent with `&`.

However, just trying to use `std::addressof`, to validate if it is the same as `&`, I meet compile error: "call to deleted function 'addressof' ". Don't know why.

Here's the minimal code to demonstrate this problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int _len): len(_len) {
        if(len>0) {
            data = new double[len];
        }
        // compile error: call to deleted function 'addressof'
        std::cout << "Foo()    " << std::addressof(this) << "/" << std::addressof(data) << std::endl;
    }
    ~Foo() {
        // compile ok
        std::cout << "~Foo()    " << (void*)this << "/" << (void*)data << std::endl;

        // compile error: call to deleted function 'addressof'
        std::cout << "~Foo()    " << std::addressof(this) << "/" << std::addressof(data) << std::endl;

        if (data!=nullptr) {
            delete[] data;
        }
    }

private:
    int len;
    double* data;
};

int main() {
    Foo(42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same reason you can't use `&this`. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: So stupid was I... I should notice that `std::addressof(this)` should be `std::addressof(*this)` but this looks more complicated..

Comment: side note: there's probably a better design *without* using `std::addressof` at all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ standard:

> §9.3.2 The this pointer
>
> the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression

[std::addressof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)

> ```
> template <class T>
> const T* addressof(const T&&) = delete;
> ```

So `addressof` overload for rvalues is deleted. The reason is because you cannot take the address of a prvalue so `addressof` is modeled to respect that.

That's why you get the error.

---

Please note that `addressof(this)` and `(void*) this` are not even in the same ballpark. The equivalent of `addressof(this)` would be `&this` which also doesn't compile.